# Как вырезать число из строки?

Tags: java, строки

От сервера приходит число в виде строки:

```
"66"
```

Как можно получить число из строки, **не используя** `substring()`?

Мой наставник дал такое задание - не могу ничего придумать.

Comment: Кавычки входят в состав строки? И что насчет количества цифр в строке, а также наличия посторонних символов?

Comment: @Regent, входят. Количество цифр любое, посторонних символов нет

Comment: Если вы получили ответ, то пометьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением

```
final String regex = "\"(\\d+)\"";
final String string = "\"66\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Не знаю, есть ли смысл учитывать в регулярном выражении кавычки - нужно ведь просто число достать.

Comment: на мой взгляд, чем строже выражение, тем меньше ложных совпадений. в исходном вопросе кавычки есть.

Answer (score 2):

Обнаружить первую группу цифр в строке и привести их к числу можно и с помощью посимвольного анализа строки:

```
String str = "\"66\"";
int number = 0;
boolean gotFirstDigit = false;
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        number = number * 10 + c - '0';
        gotFirstDigit = true;
    }
    else if (gotFirstDigit)
    {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(number);
```

Но это уже как вариант "в качестве альтернативы".